# Can anyone identify this Lego set please?

Tags: set-identification, sets

I have these parts mixed in with other Lego Bricks, but no instructions. I would like to be able to download the instructions, but I don’t know the set number. Any help to identify the set is greatly appreciated!

[image: thepartsintheset]

[image: partsintheset2]

Answer (score 8):

That's [V-19 Torrent (7674)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7674-1). Instructions are available from LEGO to [download](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&text=7674%2520V-19%2520Torrent%25E2%2584%25A2%2520Star%2520Wars%2520TM) or from Bricklink to [purchase](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?I=7674-1).

[image]

Identified by [Trans-Clear Technic, Shock Absorber 10L Damped - No Spring](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32181c03), which is available in this set only.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Roofy!  Welcome to Bricks.StackExchange.  Another great way you can show thanks is to click the checkbox by the answer to "accept" it.  https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Since roofy did not bother to click that checkmark, I have upvoted the answer (which I usually wouldn't do, it's just plain old set identifying anyway) to make it as if roofy really accepted it. Obviously my upvoting isn't enough, but at least you get some rep!